# Ant checkstyle не работает в терминале

Tags: java, ant, antlr

когда я запустила в eclipse все работало, однако в терминале все фейлится

```
checkstyle:
[checkstyle] Running Checkstyle 8.18 on 1 files
[checkstyle] Can't find/access AST Node typecom.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.DetailAST

BUILD FAILED
/home/NIX/user/eclipse-workspace/Ant/build.xml:89: Unable to process files:
```

код задачи

```
<target name="checkstyle" depends="pmd">
        <path id="checkstyle.classpath">
            <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
                <include name="*.jar" />
            </fileset>
        </path>
        <checkstyle config="${props}/checks.xml">
            <fileset dir="${collection.path}" includes="**/*.java" />
            <formatter type="xml" toFile="${build.dir.reports}/checkstyle_errors.xml" />
        </checkstyle>
    </target>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

не знаю почему в eclipse все работало, но решение лежит в удалении `antlr.jar` в `$ANT_HOME/lib`

спасибо за внимание
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466493/ant-checkstyle-task-cant-find-access-ast-node